# Ranking of various Android APK markets, by number of users

Tags: data-request, products

There are many stores proposing Android APK download:

- Google Play
- Lenovo MM
- Amazon Appstore
- OUYA Store
- Samsung Apps
- F-Droid
- etc

**QUESTION:** Is there any data available describing **how many users** these stores have?

Data about the number of apps available, and the number of downloads is welcome too, as it may indicate how well the store is doing.

*Rationale: As a developer, it takes considerable effort to publish to many different stores, many of which have instructions in Korean or Chinese. So knowing how many potential users can be reached is important.*